# Autocomplete isn't working in ajax

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I have here autocomplete script with ajax functions. I tried to get the data from database through ajax but why isn't working?

Here's my code below.. Any help will appreciate !

**Html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("autocomplete.php", { app_cn: request.term }, response);
  }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
    include('connect1.php');
if(isset($_GET["app_cn"])) {
    $auto = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($_GET["app_cn"]);
    //$selected = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);

    $sql = $mysqli1->query("SELECT id,item FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' GROUP BY item ORDER BY id"); 

    if($sql)
    {
        $str = array();
        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $str[] = $row['item'];
        }
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your console if you dont see any errors take a look at what the response is. If the response is empty add :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

just before echo json_encode($str);

$.getJSON requires the header to be application/json

Answer (score 1):

You should use success callback function in `$.getJSON`, and pass into response variable try this code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.getJSON("autocomplete.php", { app_cn: request.term }, function(data){
         response(data);
      });
    }
    });
  });
</script>
```

AND in php script

```
 $str = array();
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    {
            array_push($str, array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "label" => $row['item'],
                "value" => $row['item']
            ));
   }
   header("Content-type: text/json");
   echo json_encode($str);
```

Comment: @user3462269 what issue??

Comment: @autocomplete not working, there no data displaying in textbox

Comment: @user3462269, are you able to seen ajax response in firebug??